# ggtree dense tree issues

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtree

I am trying to plot a ggtree but am unfamiliar with how to manipulate the tree properly. I have added a picture of how my tree looks currently. I am unable to properly tell any of the branches apart and am unsure what might have caused this or how to fix this. I have the branch_length as none, as otherwise the tree is fully unreadable.

```
ggtree(mytree, layout = "circular", branch_length = "none")
```

[image: Current tree]

If anyone is able to give me a few options for how to make the tree more usable it would be great! Thank you.